# The sound didn't stop

Tags: sound, browser

I watched a video on youtube.com, and once the close the browser, the sound didn't stop. How could I stop that sound? I thought I could use `ps aux |grep chrome`, but I didn't find the pid.

Comment: If you just want it to stop, shut down the computer, unplug speakers, or even blacklist the drivers for the sound card

Comment: I agree that it was probably a hanging Chrome thread, but it takes quite a bit of detective work to find out which one. After you close the browser, if something like this happens, `killall chrome` should do the trick. If you want to delve into the mechanics of processes, file descriptors and sockets, read [this](http://www.linuxintro.org/wiki/Strace:_what_a_process_does).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tab in Chrome is managed by its own process thread. Occasionally, after Chrome is shut down, a Chrome thread will refuse to terminate. If such a thread happens to play sound, the sound may go on forever. If you want to kill a specific Chrome thread, it is in principle possible to find out its process ID and do `kill -9 <pid>`. Chrome even offers its own "Task manager" under the three-dot menu -> More tools..., or press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>.

However, once you have shut down the main Chrome program, it would take a lot of detective work which process keeps using the sound system. To get an idea of what you would need to do, read [this article](http://www.linuxintro.org/wiki/Strace:_what_a_process_does).

Fortunately, one thing you know about the noisy thread: it is called `chrome`. To kill all threads called `chrome` simply do `killall chrome` and the sound will stop.

Note that after a regular shutdown of Chrome, some threads will keep hanging around. Possibly these are busy saving browsing history; some extensions also have their own stay-resident threads. And all of these are called `chrome`.

One more tip: if one of the tabs is using so many resources that the whole PC becomes unresponsive, and you don't want to sit around waiting, you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. This will instantly kill the single process with the highest CPU load. Chances are that one of your tabs will be cleared and replaced by this icon:

> [image: Google chrome tab killed]

with some text informing you that loading your page has failed, and your computer will once again respond. Just make sure you have no heavy processing going on in the background (or the system will see that as the heaviest load) or unsaved data in the web page you are about to kill.